# Delphi Android App INDY TCP Server - Application closes after client disconnect

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7, indy10

I need help very much.

I have a TCP server application based on Indy 10's `TIdTCPServer` component, which I want to run on Win32 and Android. I'm using Delphi XE7.

The server has to handle 10 clients.

- Application works fine on Windows and Android on: CONNECTING, SENDING, RECEIVING data, but there is a problem with the `OnDisconnect` event on Android only. The application works totally fine on Windows, but on Android there is a big problem with disconnecting the clients and on event: `TCPServer.Active := FALSE`. On 90% of cases the application is being automatically closed when I disconnect a client.
- When I start the server: `TCPServer1.Active := TRUE`, and then I close it `TCPServer1.Active := FALSE`, without connecting the clients, the application works fine.

I'm adding my code under. I have used hints from Remy Lebeau.

- I'm testing the app with two clients.
- I'm showing connected clients in the ListView.
- I'm updating the ListView not from the Server Events, but in the Timer event.
- App has 3 buttons: Server Listen, Server Close, Send (clients number selected in the ListView)

Please help.

```
//  TMyContext
constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  FQueue := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
  FEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  FQueue.Free;
  FEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyContext.AddMsgToQueue(const Msg: String);
begin
  with FQueue.Lock do
  try
    Add(Msg);
    FEvent.SetEvent;
  finally
    FQueue.Unlock;
  end;
end;

function TMyContext.GetQueuedMsgs: TStrings;
var
  List: TStringList;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if FEvent.WaitFor(1000) <> wrSignaled then Exit;
  List := FQueue.Lock;
  try
    if List.Count > 0 then
    begin
      Result := TStringList.Create;
      try
        Result.Assign(List);
        List.Clear;
      except
        Result.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
    FEvent.ResetEvent;
  finally
    FQueue.Unlock;
  end;
end;

//  TCPServer

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  client    : String;
  datetime  : TDateTime;
begin
  datetime := now;

  //  CLIENT CON INFO
  client := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      TCPServer1.Contexts.LockList();
      mmoLog.Lines.Add ('CONNECT:   ' + AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP
                        + ' : ' +
                        IntToStr(AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort) + '   ' +
            DateToStr (datetime) + '   ' + TimeToStr (datetime)
      );
      TCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList();

      if TCPServer1.Contexts.Count = 1 then
        edtPort1.Text := IntToStr(AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort);

      if TCPServer1.Contexts.Count = 2 then
        edtPort2.Text := IntToStr(AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort);

      AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.Send('HELLO');

      //  CLIENTSDATA LIST
      ClientsList.Add (' ', AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP, AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort);
      LV_Refresh ();
    end
  );
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Disconnect(
  AContext: TIdContext);
var
  cl_item   :   Integer;
  datetime  :   TDateTime;
begin
  try
    datetime  := now;

    if  fSvrClose  =  FALSE then begin
      fClDiscon       := TRUE;
      buff_discon [pos_ip]    := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
      buff_discon [pos_port]  := IntToStr (AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort);
      buff_discon [pos_date]  := DateToStr (datetime);
      buff_discon [pos_time]  := TimeToStr (datetime);
    end;
  finally
    AContext.Connection.Socket.InputBuffer.Clear;
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Exception(AContext: TIdContext;
  AException: Exception);
begin
  ShowMessage ('Error');
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  buff    :   String;
  List    :   TStrings;
  I       :   Integer;
  buffout :   String;
  n       :   Integer;

  //  FOR DISCONNECT
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  clist   :   TList;
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

  {$IFDEF Android}
  clist   :   TList <TIdContext>;
  {$ENDIF Android}

begin
  if  fSvrClose = FALSE  then begin
    //  READ MESSAGES FROM THE CLIENTS
    fDisconAccess := FALSE;

    //  SEND MESSAGES TO THE CLIENTS
    List := TMyContext(AContext).GetQueuedMsgs;

    if List <> nil then begin
      try
        for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(List[I]);
      finally
        List.Free;
      end;
    end;

    //  READ MESSAGE FROM CLIENTS
    if  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(200) then begin
      buffout := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();

      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          if  AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort = StrToInt(edtPort1.Text) then begin
            edtRec1.Text := buffout;
          end;

          if AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort = StrToInt(edtPort2.Text) then begin
            edtRec2.Text := buffout;
          end;

        end
      );
    end;
    fDisconAccess := TRUE;
  end;
end;

//  USER INTERFACE

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.SendMessage (const IP : String; port : Word; Msg: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  with TCPServer1.Contexts.LockList do
  try
    for I := 0 to Count-1 do begin
      with TMyContext(Items[I]) do begin
        if  (Binding.PeerIP = IP)  and (Binding.PeerPort = port)  then begin
          AddMsgToQueue(Msg);
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Get_ClientsNum ();

  //  UPDATE UI (USER INTERFACE)
  UpdateUI ();

  //  BUTTONS
  if TCPServer1.Active = TRUE then begin
    btnListen.Enabled := FALSE;
    edtStatus.Text    := 'LISTENING';
  end else begin
    btnListen.Enabled := TRUE;
    edtStatus.Text    := 'CLOSED';
  end;

  //  ON SINGLE CLIENT DISCONNECT
  if  fClDiscon  =  TRUE  then begin
    fClDiscon := FALSE;
    CL_DeleteClient (buff_discon [pos_ip], StrToInt (buff_discon [pos_port]));
    LV_Refresh ();
    mmoLog.Lines.Add ('DISCON:   ' + buff_discon [pos_ip] + ' : ' + buff_discon [pos_port] + '   ' +
    buff_discon [pos_date] + '   ' + buff_discon [pos_time] );
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TCustomAction then
  begin
    if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> nil then
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := TabControl1.ActiveTab.Text
    else
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := '';
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  clist     : TList;
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

  {$IFDEF Android}
  clist     : TList <TIdContext>;
  {$ENDIF Android}

  i         : Integer;
  ip        : String;
  port      : Word;
  datetime  : TDateTime;
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      n : Integer;
    begin
      datetime  := now;

      if  Clients_Num  =  0  then begin
        TCPServer1.StopListening();
        TCPServer1.Active := FALSE;
      end else begin
        fSvrClose         := TRUE;

        //  SERVER CLOSE
        if fSvrClose  =  TRUE then begin
          while fDisconAccess = FALSE do begin
        end;

        try
          clist := TCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
          for  n := 0  to  (clist.Count - 1) do begin
            try
              TIdContext (clist[n]).Connection.Socket.WriteBufferClear;
              TIdContext (clist[n]).Connection.Socket.InputBuffer.Clear;
              ip    := TIdContext (clist[n]).Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
              port  := TIdContext (clist[n]).Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerPort;
              TIdContext (clist[n]).Connection.Disconnect;
              CL_DeleteClient (ip, port);
              mmoLog.Lines.Add ('DISCON:   ' + ip + ' : ' + IntToStr(port) + '   ' +
              DateToStr (datetime) + '   ' + TimeToStr (datetime) );

              sleep (100);
            except
            end;
          end;
        finally
          TCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
          TCPServer1.Active := FALSE;
          fSvrClose         := FALSE;
          LV_Refresh ();
        end;
      end;
    end
  );
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnListenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  port : Word;
begin
  port := StrToInt (edtPort.Text);
  TCPServer1.Contexts.Clear;
  TCPServer1.Bindings.Clear();

  if (port > 200)  and  (port < 65535)  then begin
    TCPServer1.DefaultPort := StrToInt (edtPort.Text);
  end else
    TCPServer1.DefaultPort := 30000;

  TCPServer1.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;

  if  TCPServer1.Active  =  FALSE  then begin
    TCPServer1.Active := TRUE;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ip    : string;
  port  : Word;
  item  : Integer;
begin
  item := LV.ItemIndex;
  if  (item  >  -1)  then begin
    ip    := ClientsList.Items[item].IP;
    port  := ClientsList.Items[item].Port;
    SendMessage (ip, port, edtSend.Text);
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.Get_ClientsNum ();
var
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  clist : TList;
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

  {$IFDEF Android}
  clist : TList <TIdContext>;
  {$ENDIF Android}
begin
  try
    clist := TCPServer1.Contexts.LockList();
    Clients_Num := TCPServer1.Contexts.Count;
  finally
    TCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not correct or safe, for Windows or Android. The fact that it works at all is *pure luck*.  There is a lot of dangerous logic in this code that needs to be re-written.

Try something more like this instead:

```
//  TMyContext

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  FQueue := TIdThreadSafeStringList.Create;
  FEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  FQueue.Free;
  FEvent.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyContext.AddMsgToQueue(const Msg: String);
begin
  with FQueue.Lock do
  try
    Add(Msg);
    FEvent.SetEvent;
  finally
    FQueue.Unlock;
  end;
end;

function TMyContext.GetQueuedMsgs: TStrings;
var
  List: TStringList;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if FEvent.WaitFor(1000) <> wrSignaled then Exit;
  List := FQueue.Lock;
  try
    if List.Count > 0 then
    begin
      Result := TStringList.Create;
      try
        Result.Assign(List);
        List.Clear;
      except
        Result.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
    FEvent.ResetEvent;
  finally
    FQueue.Unlock;
  end;
end;

//  TCPServer

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.LogMessage(Msg: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      mmoLog.Lines.Add (Msg);
    end
  );
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  clientIP  : String;
  clientPort: TIdPort;
  datetime  : TDateTime;
begin
  datetime := now;

  //  CLIENT CON INFO
  clientIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  clientPort := AContext.Binding.PeerPort;

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('HELLO');

  LogMessage('CONNECT:   ' + clientIP + ' : ' + IntToStr(clientPort) + '   ' + DateToStr (datetime) + '   ' + TimeToStr (datetime));

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      client: string;
    begin
      client := clientIP + ':' + IntToStr(clientPort);

      case TCPServer1.Contexts.Count of
        1: edtPort1.Text := client;
        2: edtPort2.Text := client;
      end;

      //  CLIENTSDATA LIST
      ClientsList.Add (' ', clientIP, clientPort);
      LV_Refresh;
    end
  );
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Disconnect(
  AContext: TIdContext);
var
  datetime  :   TDateTime;
  clientIP  : String;
  clientPort: TIdPort;
begin
  datetime  := now;

  //  CLIENT CON INFO
  clientIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  clientPort := AContext.Binding.PeerPort;

  LogMessage('DISCON:   ' + clientIP + ' : ' + IntToStr(clientPort) + '   ' + DateToStr(datetime)  + '   ' + TimeToStr(datetime));

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      client: string;
    begin
      client := clientIP + ':' + IntToStr(clientPort);

      if edtPort1.Text = client then begin
        edtPort1.Text := '';
      end;

      if edtPort2.Text = client then begin
        edtPort2.Text := '';
      end;

      CL_DeleteClient (clientIP, clientPort);
      if fSvrClose = FALSE then LV_Refresh;
    end
  );
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Exception(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  if fSvrClose = FALSE then
    LogMessage ('Error: ' + AException.Message);
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  buff    :   String;
  List    :   TStrings;
  I       :   Integer;
  clientIP:   String;
  clientPort: TIdPort;
begin
  if fSvrClose = TRUE then Exit;

  //  SEND MESSAGES TO THE CLIENTS
  List := TMyContext(AContext).GetQueuedMsgs;

  if List <> nil then
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(List[I]);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;

  if fSvrClose = TRUE then Exit;

  //  READ MESSAGE FROM CLIENTS
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(200);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if fSvrClose = TRUE then Exit;
  end;

  if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then begin
  begin
    buff := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
    if fSvrClose = TRUE then Exit;

    clientIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
    clientPort := AContext.Binding.PeerPort;

    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      var
        client: string;
      begin
        client := clientIP + ':' + IntToStr(clientPort);

        if edtPort1.Text = client then begin
          edtRec1.Text := buff;
        end;

        if edtPort2.Text = client then begin
          edtRec2.Text := buff;
        end;
      end
    );
  end;
end;

//  USER INTERFACE

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.SendMessage (const IP : String; port : TIdPort; const Msg: string);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  with TCPServer1.Contexts.LockList do
  try
    for I := 0 to Count-1 do begin
      with TMyContext(Items[I]) do begin
        if (Binding <> nil) and (Binding.PeerIP = IP)  and (Binding.PeerPort = port) then begin
          AddMsgToQueue(Msg);
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Get_ClientsNum;

  //  UPDATE UI (USER INTERFACE)
  UpdateUI;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TCustomAction then
  begin
    if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> nil then
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := TabControl1.ActiveTab.Text
    else
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := '';
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fSvrClose := TRUE;

  // SERVER CLOSE
  TCPServer1.Active := FALSE;
  btnListen.Enabled := TRUE;
  edtStatus.Text    := 'CLOSED';

  fSvrClose := FALSE;
  LV_Refresh;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnListenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  port : TIdPort;
begin
  port := StrToInt (edtPort.Text);

  TCPServer1.Active := False;
  TCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;

  if (port > 200)  and  (port < 65535)  then begin
    TCPServer1.DefaultPort := port;
  end else
    TCPServer1.DefaultPort := 30000;

  TCPServer1.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  TCPServer1.Active := TRUE;

  btnListen.Enabled := FALSE;
  edtStatus.Text    := 'LISTENING';
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ip    : string;
  port  : Word;
  item  : Integer;
begin
  item := LV.ItemIndex;
  if (item > -1) then begin
    ip    := ClientsList.Items[item].IP;
    port  := ClientsList.Items[item].Port;
    SendMessage (ip, port, edtSend.Text);
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.Get_ClientsNum;
begin
  Clients_Num := TCPServer1.Contexts.Count;
end;
```

Comment: Thank You Remy Lebeau for Your answer. 
You have right. My code was so because I was trying a lot of different combinations and it's my first app using INDY. 
I have update my app with You're code hints. It's working smooth and fast and little bit more stable ... but there is still the same problem. On 80% of cases the application is being automatically closed when I disconnect a client/clients on Android devices. I was testing it on two different tablets and it's work the same.
I have deleted functions connected with ListView and nothing better.
Can my problem be connected with Memo or Edit?

Comment: Is there a possibility in INDY that app is accessing a client thread, when it is actually being disconnected?

Comment: I see nothing in this code that can kill the app when a client disconnects. So something else has to be killing the app.  For instance, what does `UpdateUI()` actually do? You did not show that code. And why are you using a timer to update the UI, instead of using events or queued methods to update the UI when changes are actually needed?

Comment: Super! I've got the answer!
The problem was on Android side. In an act of desperation I have tried to install my app on Android 5.1 Lollipop on my mobile and everything works just perfect! The previous tablets works on Android Jelly Bean. I think here is the problem. Can Delphi switch automatically to the correct SDK or I have to switch something manually? I'm installing the SKD for Jelly Bean now and I will try to run it again. 
Thank You very much Remy for Your proffesional help! I will write here how it works after SDK install.
Best Regards.

Comment: This is incredible. I still have the same problem. I have tried to build my app with the most of the SDK API versions. Now, I have installed API: 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21 and 23. I have built my app with all of thoose API versions and nothing! The app works fine only od device with Android 5.0 (API 21) and can be built with API 15-23. The app is not working properly on devices with Android 4.2.1 (API 17), and on Android 4.1 (API 16). There is still the same problem. App is beeing killed on client disconnect event.
I'm setting SDK at: Tools>Options>SDK Manager and Add. Please HELP!

Comment: Is the problem happening every time you disconnect a client while leaving the server running? Or does the problem only occur when deactivating the server while clients are still connected? Android is *very* sensitive to main UI thread blockages. If you block the main thread for a noticeable amount of time, Android will consider the app unresponsive and kill it. Deactivating the server in the main thread will block until all client threads have terminated, and you do have a blocking wait in the `GetQueuedMsgs` method. So either rewrite that wait, or deactivate the server in a worker thread.

Comment: The problem is happening almost every time when disconnecting the client/clients and deactivating the Server. There are single cases when disconnect/deactivate event goes well, but only when one client is connected. When there are few clients connected the disconnect and deactivate event always goes wrong. I have tested my app even when there was all the UI functions disabled and nothing.
The only case when my app works smooth and stable is on the Android 5.0 API 21.
The app is closed without ANY warning or info.
I have shown my UI code below.

Comment: I have also one notice.
The android app is being killed immediately when there is problem with variables values. For example:

devtype := ClientsList.GetType (item);

    case  devtype  of

        CPV_DEV:    CPV_FMX.Form1.Show;

        CWT_DEV:    CWT_FMX.Form2.Show;
        
        else

            ShowMessage ('Device not registered');

    end;

When the devtype value is '-1' then the app is being killed without any warning! I think something similar is happening 'on disconnect' event. Very strange!

Comment: Without knowing what `devtype` is declared as, or what `GetType()` returns, I can only assume that a value of -1 is probably causing an `ERangeError` exception to be raised that you are not catching, thus killing the app if raised in the main UI thread. `OnDisconnect` is triggered in a worker thread instead, so it can't just kill the app, unless you sync with the main UI thread and IT then does something to kill the app.

Comment: Also, note that `ShowMessage()` is asynchronous on mobile platforms, so if you are expecting it to be synchronous like it is on desktop platforms, you will need to update your code accordingly. This is covered in Embarcadero's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening almost every time when disconnecting the client/clients and deactivating the Server. There are single cases when disconnect/deactivate event goes well, but only when one client is connected. When there is few clients connected the disconnect and deactivate event always goes wrong. I have tested my app even when there was all the UI functions disabled and no improvement.
The only case where my app works smooth and stable is on the Android 5.0 Lollipop API 21 on my mobile. I can disconnect all clients one after another and I can deactivate the server with connected clients and everything works fine even with UI functions enabled. 
Maybe there are some system configuration to do on older versions of Android like Jelly Bean or in Delphi? It is a pity that I can't upgrade my tablet to API 5.0.

To be exact I will show You the UI functions:
(I'm making my own ClientsList because I have to remember more data like device name or serial number. It is easier to do with my own code.)

```
<code>

//  -----------------------------------------------------------------  LIST VIEW
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.LV_MakeLine;
var
  Item  :  TListItem;
begin
    Item := LV.Items.Add;
end;


procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.LV_AddData (index : Word);
var
  Item    : TListItem;
  Client  : TClientTcp;
  ip      : String;
  port    : String;
  name    : String;
begin
    Client  := ClientsList.Items [index];
    Item    := LV.Items.Item [index];
    LV.Items.Item [index].Text := Client.Name + ' ' + Client.IP + ' : ' + IntToStr(Client.Port);
end;


procedure  THeaderFooterwithNavigation.LV_Refresh;
var
    i     : Integer;
    itms  : Integer;
begin
    LV.Items.Clear;
    //LV.ClearItems;

    itms := ClientsList.Count;
    for  i := 0  to  itms-1  do begin
        LV_MakeLine ();
        LV_AddData (i);
    end;
end;


procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.CL_DeleteClient (ip : String; port : Word);
var
    cl_item   :   Integer;
begin
    cl_item := ClientsList.FindClient_ByIpPort (ip, port);
    if  cl_item  >  (-1)  then begin
        //  DELETE DISCONNECTED CLIENT FROM LIST AND SET LIST SIZE TO THE CLIENTS NUMBER
        ClientsList.Delete (cl_item);
    end;
end;
```

and the Clients List

```
unit ServerTcpA;

interface
{
uses
  SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Generics.Collections;
}


uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  System.Generics.Collections;


{
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Contnrs, ComCtrls,
  Buttons, WinSock, ScktComp;
}

type
    //  CLASS DECLARATIONS  ----------------------------------------------------


    //  TClientTcp  CLASS  -----------------------------------------------------
    TClientTcp  = class (TObject)
        public
            Name        : String;
            IP          : String;
            Port        : Integer;
            RecFrames   : Integer;
    end;



    //  TClientsTcpList CLASS  -------------------------------------------------
    TClientsTcpList = class (TObjectList <TObject>)
        private
            function  FGetItem  (index : Integer)   : TClientTcp;
        public
            property  Items               [index : Integer]   : TClientTcp read FGetItem;
            function  Add                 (name : String; ip : String; port: Integer) : TClientTcp;
            function  FindClient_ByName   (name : String)   : TClientTcp;
            function  FindClient_ByIp     (ip   : String)   : TClientTcp;
            function  FindClient_ByPort   (port : Integer)  : Integer;
            function  FindClient_ByIpPort (ip : String; port : Integer): Integer;
    end;



    //  TTcpCfg CLASS  ---------------------------------------------------------
    TTcpCfg = class (TObject)
        TcpClientsList    : TClientsTcpList;

        public
            constructor   Create;
            destructor    Destroy;    override;
            function      AddClient   (ip : String;  port: Integer) : TClientTcp;
    end;



    //  ENUM - Defined Column Names  -------------------------------------------
    type TColNames = (
        COL_LP = 0,
        COL_NAME,
        COL_IP,
        COL_PORT
    );



const
    NONE  = -1;



var
    //ServerTcpDK  : TServerSocket;
    //TCPCFG    :   TTcpCfg;
    ClientsList : TClientsTcpList;


implementation





//  ===================================================  CLASS:  TClientsTcpList

//  GET ITEM
function TClientsTcpList.FGetItem (index : Integer) : TClientTcp;
begin
    //Result  := inherited GetItem (index) as TClientTcp;
    Result  := inherited Items [index] as TClientTcp;
end;


//  ADD ITEM
function TClientsTcpList.Add (name : String; ip : String; port: Integer) : TClientTcp;
begin
    if  (FindClient_ByIpPort (ip, port) = NONE)  then begin
        Result            := TClientTcp.Create;
        Result.Name       := name;
        Result.IP         := ip;
        Result.Port       := port;
        Result.RecFrames  := 0;

        inherited Add (Result);
    end;
end;



//  FIND CLIENT: BY NAME
function TClientsTcpList.FindClient_ByName (name : String): TClientTcp;
var
  i : integer;
begin
    //Result := nil;
    Result := nil;

    for  i:=0  to  Count-1  do  begin
        if Items [i].Name = name  then begin
            Result := Items[i];
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;



//  FIND CLIENT: BY IP
function TClientsTcpList.FindClient_ByIp (ip : String): TClientTcp;
var
  i : integer;
begin
    //Result := nil;
    Result := nil;

    for  i:=0  to  Count-1  do  begin
        if Items [i].IP = ip  then begin
            Result := Items[i];
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;



//  FIND CLIENT: BY PORT  ------------------------------------------------------
//  @Ret:   Item Index in the LIST
//          -1: Not Found
function TClientsTcpList.FindClient_ByPort (port : Integer): Integer;
var
  i   : integer;
begin
    Result := NONE;

    for  i:=0  to  Count-1  do  begin
        if Items [i].Port = port  then begin
            Result := i;
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;



//  FIND CLIENT: BY IP AND PORT  -----------------------------------------------
//  @Ret:   Item Index in the LIST
//          -1: Not Found
function TClientsTcpList.FindClient_ByIpPort (ip : String; port : Integer): Integer;
var
  i   : integer;
begin
    Result := NONE;

    for  i:=0  to  Count-1  do  begin
        if  (Items [i].IP = ip) and (Items [i].Port = port)  then begin
            Result := i;
            break;
        end;
    end;
end;



//  ===========================================================  CLASS:  TTcpCfg
constructor TTcpCfg.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    TcpClientsList  := TClientsTcpList.Create;
end;



destructor TTcpCfg.Destroy;
begin
    TcpClientsList.Free;
    inherited;
end;



function TTcpCfg.AddClient (ip : String;  port: Integer) : TClientTcp;
begin
    Result := TClientTcp.Create;
    //TcpClientsList.Add (Result);

    Result.IP         := ip;
    Result.Port       := port;
    Result.RecFrames  := 0;
end;



//  ============================================================  INITIALIZATION
initialization
    //ServerTcpDK := TServerSocket.Create (Nil);
    //TCPCFG := TTcpCfg.Create;
    ClientsList := TClientsTcpList.Create;


finalization
    //ServerTcpDK.Free;
    //TCPCFG.Free;
    ClientsList.Free;


//  @END OF FILE  --------------------------------------------------------------
end.
```